# Why can't I assign all padding values?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to change all paddings of the html element with js, like:

```
const pd = 1
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingRight = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingLeft = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingTop = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingBottom = pd + 'px'
```

but it sets the padding to 1px.

If one of the lines is removed eg.:

```
const pd = 1
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingRight = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingTop = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingBottom = pd + 'px'
```

other values are set properly.

Can anyone explain why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: "it sets the padding to 1px." That's what your code does. What's the problem? I don't see it. Edit: if it says padding is 1px, without specifying a side, that means, 'on all sides'.

Comment: Are you finding this out by looking at your browser's dev tools inspect facilityy? If you look at the styles you will see padding: 1px with something like a little arrow beside it. Click that and it will expand to show you all four values spelled out. Or look at the computed styles which will give you a list of all the style values. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: removed css tag, that would be for `.board:first-of-type{padding:var(--pd)}`

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't comment so i trying to answer

Can you show me your test results and what do you want

There's nothing wrong with your javascript script

If you want to change all the padding why not

```
 selector.style.padding = "1px"
```

Or

```
 Selector.style.padding = "1px 1px 1px 1px"
```

What is the reason you type that much?

Comment: really, should just do a *best attempt answer* and not ask the OP any questions, or not answer at all. if you just answer, then you may get upvoted, then when you have enough rep you can ask questions in comments

Comment: Yes, I understand that sir and I think my answer might also answer the question a bit

Answer (score 0):

When you set the same value (in your example 1px) for the following CSS properties:
`padding-bottom`,`padding-left`,`padding-right`,`padding-top` (all sides) - it's the same as `padding: 1px;`.

Moreover, if you set the same value (for example 2px) for `padding-right` and `padding-left`, and the same value for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` (for example 1px) - you will see `padding: 1px 2px`;

Snippet:

```js
var pd = 1;
var pd2 = 2;
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingTop = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingRight = pd2 + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingBottom = pd + 'px'
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.paddingLeft = pd2 + 'px'
```

```html
  <div class="board">board</div>
```

Check this [MDN's chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#constituent_properties) to see all combination.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are passing an Integer instead a String, in order to change the padding property you should use a string.

There are many ways to solve it but if all the paddings are the same then just modify padding property.

Change your const to string:

```
const pd = '1';
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].style.padding = pd;
```

'1' is taken as 1px by default, if you want to specify other metrics then write it, like '1em', '1%', etc.

Also, you may use

```
document.querySelector('.board')
```

to select the first element with board class instead select all and modify by index